# How to use Express middleware after Apollo-Server v2 middleware?

Tags: node.js, express, apollo-server

I'm having this weird requirement(because I got nothing on the internet on how to use it. So, I guess it's only me) while using Express and Apollo Server.

I want to use an Express middleware after using the Apollo Server middleware but I can't.

**Example**:

```
const { ApolloServer } = require('apollo-server-express');
const express = require('express')

const app = express();
const server = new ApolloServer({typedefs, resolvers})

app.use(...); // Middleware-1
app.use(...); // Middleware-2
app.use(server.getMiddleware()); // Apollo server middleware
app.use(...); // Middleware-3

app.listen({ port: 4000 }, () =>
  console.log(` Server ready at http://localhost:4000${server.graphqlPath}`)
);
```

In the above code, the **Middleware-3** is never being called. I've searched a lot about that but I got nothing.

Is there any way to invoke **Middleware-3** after **Apollo Server Middleware**?

Thank you.

---

**Edit:1**
I forgot to mention that I don't want to modify the response from the ApolloServer. I already have some Express middlewares which I don't want to refactor/modify/write completely new ones to be able to use along with Apollo. So, is there any hacky way to follow the `app.use()` order even after ApolloServer middleware?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to assign

`res.end2 = res.end
res.end = ()=>{}`

in any middleware called before ApolloMidleware and then call `res.end2` to the send response

Comment: But to get to the next middleware, how can I access  and where can I call the `next()` in ApolloMiddleware?

Comment: @unknownymouse: i come up a solution https://repl.it/@cymruu/SpiffyPinkExtensions but it's owful hack and should not be used

Answer (score 2):

Apollo Server calls [res.end](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.end) after sending the execution results of your GraphQL request. This finalizes the response, so no other middleware will be called afterward.

If you need to format the response, you can utilize the `formatResponse` or `formatErrors` options, but you cannot use Express middleware.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I don't want to modify the response from the ApolloServer. I already have some Express middlewares which I don't want to refactor/modify/write completely new ones to be able to use along with Apollo. So, is there any hacky way to follow the `app.use()` order even after ApolloServer middleware?

Comment: If you're not modifying the response, it's not really clear why applying the middleware before as opposed to after would make a difference.